# WebExtensions: What is the point onConnect? It seems redundant to onMessage

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I was trying to figure out how to identify which (of many) created tabs send messages to a background script, and thought that the way to go was *sender.tab.id* in background.js's *browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, **sender**, respF)=>{})*

But then I came across onConnect, which passes a *runtime.Port* object to its handler. Could it be used to more elegantly identify which tab tried talking to background? If not, what is the point of onConnect?

Comment: Don't know anything about Firefox extensions, but those methods seem to be exactly the same as a websocket. `onConnect()` would be confirmation that a connection was established. `onMessage()` is when data is received from the websocket.

Comment: As the documentation says, it's for a long-lived connection. You can use it when sending dozens or hundreds of messages per second to avoid recreating the internal port.

Comment: @wOxxOm I guess you're right, though I'd say the examples in documentation make no effort to mention or demonstrate the intense-communication aspect. And without it, it's a bit of a confusing mix approaches of broadcasting to everything that listens VS talking to a specific port only, both seemingly accomplishing the same job.

Answer (score 0):

Point of `onConnect` is to provide you a `state` change where you manage your onConnect logic - usually modify your listeners.

e.g.

- `addListener` which should be active when connected
- `removeListener` which should be disabled when connected
- `hasListener` check does connected instance have that listener already
- etc. e.g. additionally `onConnectExternal`